# Oauth2Client service account using a json API key

Tags: python, json, google-sheets, oauth2client

I am building an app using google's drive API and I am using a JSON API key.  Whenever I run the following code:

```
# these are api managing credentials
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheets']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json('client_secret', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)  # this connects the the google api using credentials
```

I get this weird error message:

```
File "C:/Users/Will Kaiser's PC/Documents/PyCharm/Projects/ph/main.py", line 16, in <module>
  creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json('client_secret.json', scope)
  TypeError: from_json() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

This to me is a very weird error since I am giving the function 2 arguments.  My keys are in a JSON file and all of that is done correctly.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation [here](http://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.service_account.html#oauth2client.service_account.ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json):

> classmethod from_json(json_data)   Deserialize a JSON-serialized
>   instance.
>
> Inverse to to_json().
>
> Parameters: json_data – dict or string, Serialized JSON (as a string
>   or an already parsed dictionary) representing a credential.
>
> Returns: ServiceAccountCredentials from the serialized data.

So actually accepts 1 argument and not two.

Note that in Python there n+1 arguments (hence you see the error message 2 arguments but three given) because the `self` is implicitly passed to the method and hence when you call a method on an object instance you are passing the instance itself implicitly plus your arguments explicitly.